# Where can I get insurance for travel in late pregnancy?

Tags: usa, insurance, pregnancy

My wife and I need to travel to the United States, but she will be 30 weeks pregnant by the time the trip ends.  In addition to it being a very good idea in general, the US [effectively requires travel insurance](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/882/~/visit-the-u.s.-while-pregnant-and-the-risks-involved) if you're pregnant, but most travel insurance policies only offer cover until 26 weeks.  Where can we get a policy that covers her?

Comment: I have a better question:  Did airline allow your wife to fly?

Comment: Most airlines are happy to let you fly even at 40+ weeks as long as your doctor says it's OK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insurance for travel to the USA while pregnant](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25212/insurance-for-travel-to-the-usa-while-pregnant)

Comment: Oi close voters -- a) this question is older, b) late pregnancy != 5 weeks into pregnancy and c) the "answers" in the other question are useless.

Comment: Those country differences in insurance tradition are interesting. You didn’t mention your home country in the question, but from your self-answer I gather it’s Australia. In Germany, practically all travel insurance covers pregnancy until week 36.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Answering my own question because this took a lot of legwork:

We found precisely two insurers who cover travel beyond 26 weeks.  (Only for uncomplicated births: no multiples (twins), no IVF.)

- [Columbus Direct](http://www.columbusdirect.com/help/faqs/medical-health/is-pregnancy-covered/) offers coverage up to 36 weeks in *some* countries.  However, if you're based in Australia, [their limit appears to be 30 weeks](http://www.columbusdirect.com.au/travel_insurance_faq.asp#13), and that requires an expensive "Pregnancy Extension Option" that pushed the insurance price to over $800 for 5 weeks (!).
- [ihi Bupa](https://www.ihi.com) offers cover [up to 36 weeks inclusive](http://global.ihi.com/travel+insurance/travel+advice/travel+guide/pregnancy.aspx) as a part of their standard policy, and will even provide a letter on request stating so (handy for those US immigration authorities).  They're happy to insure residents of any country for travel to virtually any country, and while not cheap, at 323 euros the cost was still about half of what Columbus wanted.

No prizes for guessing which one we went with!

*Update*: In the end, neither check-in nor US immigration noticed my wife is pregnant, and the birth occurred outside the US as well.  So we never had to "test out" the insurance.

Answer (score 1):

jpatokal depending on your duration of visit, are you sure you have read all the clauses in case the delivery happens in the US ? Just so you are informed (and since I have seen a lot of friends suffer) :

Most insurance companies will deny any delivery related claims stating that pregnancy was pre existing when you bought the insurance and if pregnancy specifically isn't covered (pregnancy rider ?) as a pre existing condition then it will take a lot of running around to get your insurance claims. There seems to be a law in place for this specific situation which you will have to google for. From here : http://blogs.webmd.com/health-insurance-navigator/2012/02/three-health-insurance-mistakes-women-should-avoid.html 
 *if you just learned that you’re pregnant and don’t have insurance, you can’t bet on being able to buy coverage now. Pregnancy is considered a pre-existing medical condition and typically leads to denial of coverage for a woman who applies for insurance on the private market.*

Comment: Is the no-preexisting conditions denial still legal?  It was on the list of things to be removed by ObamaCare; but with the staggered implementation I'm not sure if it's gone into effect yet or not.

Comment: @DanNeely: I'm not even sure that the Obamacare rules would apply to travel insurance at all.

Comment: Yes, of course we checked that, and ihi Bupa's wording is unambiguous: "You will be covered up until and incl. the 36th week of your pregnancy ... Premature birth is covered if it can be documented that you have not had any complications related to the pregnancy prior to your trip."

Comment: Also, the link you posted is about general *health* insurance, where you'll almost always have a 12-month waiting period for pregnancy, but this is about *travel* insurance.

Comment: _she will be 30 weeks pregnant by the time the trip **ends**_ I didnt read the ends part before. My answer was more in lines of 'what if the delivery happens in US'. I will let the answer be, hoping it helps some one in future. And this is the response from the Bupa insurance chat when I asked what if the delivery happens in US :

Comment: _In regard to pregnancy, there is no cover after the 36th week of pregnancy, or after the 18th week if the pregnancy is a result of fertility treatment or you are expecting more than one child (Please see art. 23.1.7). Premature birth is covered if it can be documented that the policyholder has not had any complications related to the pregnancy before the start of the trip._