# Is an Australian travel insurance company right not to honor a cancellation claim even if I can't enter the country while pregnant?

Tags: australia, insurance, pregnancy

So I've booked tickets to Malaysia about a year ago after we found some super cheap tickets (non-refundable, non-changeable). A couple of months after booking the ticket, I got pregnant, and will be in my third trimester when we go on this flight.

We rang up the insurance company and according to them, pregnancy is a pre-existing condition and therefore is not covered. It is [considered preexisting](http://www.westpac.com.au/docs/pdf/pb/westpac_credit_card_comp_insurance_policy_after21Oct2012) even through this all occurred after the booking of the tickets.

The problem is that Malaysia [doesn't give out visas to pregnant women after the 6th month of pregnancy](http://visados.com/en/visa-for-Malaysia). We wouldn't be allowed to go even if we wanted to.

So do I have some sort of case here for me to complain somehow (to somebody?) or is this quite standard process and I should just accept that we won't get our money back?

Comment: Why not just reschedule the flight?

Comment: non-changeable, non-refundable flights

Comment: A lot of airlines allow changing the ticket for a fee.  Anyhow I would suggest getting a lawyer since based on the policy description it takes effect at the time of travel for which your pregnancy will be a preexisting condition on the other hand I haven't read the entire policy but you might be able to change the ticket and have the company pick up the bill if there was another reason for you not to travel.  Although given that you have already told the company the company that pregnancy is the reason I would suggest consulting a lawyer.

Comment: Even if it were possible to change it, would you still want to travel (with the baby?) within a few months after giving birth?  If not, then all this talk of changing the flight is pointless.  (Or, is it possible to travel before you are 6 months along?  I can't quite work out from the timeline whether that ship has sailed, too.)

Comment: If I were you, I would just ignore that silly rule and go for it.  Unless your wife is massively pregnant-looking, Immigration is unlikely to notice or care; I traveled with my wife when she was 7 months pregnant, and nobody ever noticed.  (Do get some insurance though: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14895/where-can-i-get-insurance-for-travel-in-late-pregnancy)

Answer (score 5):

Most trip cancellation insurance is designed to cover for unexpected occurrences, accidents, illnesses, etc.  Pregnancy on the other hand is often considered a controllable occurrence.  While some pregnancies are unexpected, those become more of a "we didn't you did" argument and the insurance company usually wins.

Buried deep within the terms of your coverage, there is likely a definition of coverage regarding pregnancy.  You might be able to track it down yourself or might need a legal eagle to help understand your options.  But check the wording before giving up.

Also with the airline, as your issue is medical you may be able to get them to waive the non-changeable rule and let you reschedule for a fee.  But you need to approach it from a very polite point of view, explaining the situation and your desire to again travel on their airline to that destination.  Threats or rants will immediately get your request deep sixed.  Do a little web research and try to find email contacts for upper management to address your request to.

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned you booked holiday a year in advance, but when did you purchase your travel insurance?  You cannot purchase travel insurance a year before you travel, so I guess it depends on whether you were pregnant before or after purchasing your travel insurance.  This site http://www.comparetravelinsurance.com.au/tips-and-guides/pregnancy-travel-insurance-guide  has a good guide on pregnancy and travel insurance